# Failed to get ComputerName in Powershell Get-Eventlog

Tags: powershell, get-eventlog

In Security section in Event Viewer, there is a column named "Computer".

I am using powershell to retrieve "all event ID 100" as of yesterday and display columns "event ID" and "computer".

```
Get-EventLog Security -After "2016-08-25 08:08:08" | Where-Object { ($_.instanceid) -eq 100 } | select-object "computer", "instanceID"
```

However, it only shows blank records for `Computer` column.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it with `MachineName` like so

```
... select-object "MachineName", "instanceID"
```

You can find that out when piping your objects to

```
Get-EventLog ... | Get-Member
```

where you will find a property `MachineName`